# PHP to search SQL DB beween dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL DB where I store information according to dates and times.

The format the SQL stores in is 2013-04-25 15:13:37

The column name is date_time and is Var

My seach PHP is as follow:

```
<form action="control_lbsresult.php" method="get">
                <input type="hidden" name="member_msisdn" value="<?=$query?>" 
/>
                <input type="text" name="query" />
                <br />
                <label for="dates"></label>
                <input type="date" name="dates" id="dates" />
                 Start Date<br />
                <label for="datee"></label>
                <input type="date" name="datee" id="datee" />
                 End Date<br />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </form>
```

This is the string what it gives in URL

```
/control_lbsresult.php?member_msisdn=&query=0827910119&dates=2013-04-01&datee=2013-04-
25
```

This is what i have in my result page:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="***"; // Mysql username 
$password="****"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="****"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="lbs_"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE date between  '" . $dates . "' AND '" . $datee . "'    
msisdn='$msisdn'";
```

It is not filtering between the dates for me and gives me all the results of the MSISDN

I think the problem is in the WHERE string please assist

Comment: If your dates are stored as strings mysql won't treat them as dates. You should change that data type to datetime.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: `$dates` and `$datee` aren't defined anywhere in your code, and the `msisdn` part will cause a syntax error in the SQl as well.

Comment: Please read up on [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) before you do any more SQL programming. What you're doing here is reckless and could cost you severely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BETWEEN` with dates can get you unexpected rsults. Try this instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM $tbl_name 
WHERE date >=  '" . $dates . "' 
AND date <= '" . $datee . "'
```

Comment: Unlikely OP will get the results they want with a string.

Comment: BETWEEN works totally fine with dates if the value is stored in a proper date, datetime, or timestamp field.

Comment: What do you mean "unexpected results"? `BETWEEN` is almost always better than `x >= y AND x <= z`.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE date >=  '" . $dates . "' AND date <= '" . $datee . "'  msisdn='$msisdn'

I am not defining $dates or $datee as Marc B is saying but how do i draw it from the URL string. It shows me all results still

Comment: Ok here is what I got to work

    ("SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE date >=  '" . $dates . "' 
    AND date <= '" . $datee . "' AND msisdn='$query'");

I have changed code saved tested and then discovered I was using the wrong PHP page and not altering the one I was linking to. Thanks all and excuse my tiredness late at night not thinking straight

Answer (score 1):

Use `BETWEEN` or `>= & <=`, both should work.

You need to make sure that field type is `DATE`.

Also, i would suggest to use mysqli.

Following is the sample code for you:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE date_field between ? AND ?");

$stmt->bind_param("ss",$start_date,$end_date);

$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the type of your column.

   `ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN` date `datetime;`
2. Use `BETWEEN`.